# iOS push notification is not working

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

For push notifications i am using C# service.

Notification sent at server side but Push notification not coming to device.

I added my server side code and ios code below please check and help me.

Thank you in advance.

Ios code:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];

    }
 -(void)registerRemoteNotifications:(UIApplication *)application {
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}
(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    NSString *devToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:devToken forKey:kRIDeviceToken];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:kRIDeviceToken];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

server side code (c#):

```
 int port = 2195;
                String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
                String certificatePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ios/pushNotificationCert.p12");
                X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), "xxxxxxx");
                X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
                SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

                try
                {
                    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)32);

                    writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(notificationId.ToUpper()));
                    String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Hi,This Is a Sample Push Notification For IPhone.." + "\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
                    writer.Write((byte)0);
                    writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
                    byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
                    writer.Write(b1);
                    writer.Flush();
                    byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    sslStream.Write(array);
                    sslStream.Flush();
                    client.Close();
                }
                catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
                {
                    client.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your push to the Apple production server. There are two servers, production and development (also known as sandbox). 
However you are almost certainly running your app in development mode, and a development app and production server are not compatible. Change to use the sandbox server.